# Self-signed SSL certificate when developing app on Facebook

Tags: facebook, ssl, facebook-php-sdk

I'm new to developing apps on Facebook, I encountered some problems.
As it turned out facebook requires my Canvas URL to use SSL.

I use Open Server which uses it's own SSL cert. I have set Secure Canvas URL as following "`https://localhost/`"

`https://localhost/` opens in any browser fine, But when I try to open facebook app it says that it doesn't trust the certificate because it's self-signed with the following error

> "sec_error_untrusted_issuer"

(I am using Mozilla).
And it doesn't provide me with option to trust this certificate.
So what can I do?
I just want to make a "Hello World" app on facebook. And I don't want to buy any certificates.

Answer (score 1):

I'm dealing with this question as well..   (I find IE11 won't show the app either).

It does seem that a facebook app/tab page will show in Chrome with a self-signed cert - so you could try doing your development / testing in chrome as a workaruond.

In firefox this workaround seems to work as well for local development purposes: right-click in the frame for the facebook app, select 'This Frame' -> 'Show only this frame'.  It will open just the facebook app, and give a warning.. click 'I understand the risks', the confirm/add the exception.  When you then return to the facebook page with the app frame, your app should be displayed